# jQuery UI autocomplete fire new event after selecting an item

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am using jQuery UI autocomplete and I am trying to implement some code where once the user has picked an item from the autocomplete dropdown it calls another function. I have looked at the API documentation but with little progress.

```
 // Call LookUpGroupName ActionResult in UserManager Controller
 $("#group_name").autocomplete(
     '@Url.Action("LookUpGroupName", "UserManager")', {
     dataType: 'json',
     parse: function (data) {
         var rows = new Array();
         for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
             rows[i] = {
                 data: data[i],
                 value: data[i].group,
                 result: data[i].group
             }
         }
         return rows;
     },
     formatItem: function (row, i, max) {
         return row.group;
     },
     width: 300,
     highlight: false,
     multiple: false,
     open: function () {
         alert("changed");
     }

 }); // End of autocomplete
```

Once I have selected an item I want to fire a function which displays an alert. How do I do this?

Comment: What version of jQuery UI is used? I don't recognize these options here, but `select` event is raised when user chooses an item from the menu, not `open`.

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select

Answer (score 2):

Use Autocomplete's select: option. Something like.

```
select: function (event, ui){
alert("|" + $("#targetID").val() + "|1stAlert");
}
```