# Jquery autocomplete one input more values

Tags: jquery, input

my title is maybe a bit hard to understand. I am trying to do following with
jquery autocomplete:

see this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/96Y2y/

If a User types "j" he get´s Jochen + John. So far so good. Lets say he chooses
john. what I want know is, after he has choosen John everything in the input
is cutted except the number in brackets. the Result should look like:

7,

after this action the user should be abled to start writing a name again after the comma,
let´s say he writes "chris", after his selection the input should look like:

7, 9

and so on. Is this possible?

I think first step would be to check a "onfinishedselect" action

```
select: function (event, ui){
alert("|" + $("#targetID").val() + "|1stAlert");
}
```

like in this post: [jQuery UI autocomplete fire new event after selecting an item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13843750/jquery-ui-autocomplete-fire-new-event-after-selecting-an-item)

Kind regards, and thanks for help,

tony

Comment: You can look at http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/ as an alternare

Comment: You can have a look at select2 http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6pMAq/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the code for the [multiple values demo](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple) and have a regular expression to insert only the number between parentheses:

```
function extractLast( term ) {
    return split( term ).pop();
}

function split( val ) {
    return val.split( /,\s*/ );
}

$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
        "Max (1)", 
        "Paul (3)",
        "John (7)",
        "Jochen (11)",
        "Chris (9)"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ) .autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: function( request, response ) {
            // We trim the search term before comparing to the source
            request.term = $.trim(request.term);
            // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
            response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                availableTags, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
        },
        focus: function() {
            // prevent value inserted on focus
            return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            var terms = split( this.value );
            // remove the current input
            terms.pop();
            // add the number between parentheses for the selected item
            var num = ui.item.value.match(/\((\d+)\)/);
            var value = num[1];
            terms.push( value );
            // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
            terms.push( "" );
            this.value = terms.join( "," );
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

See the jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/96Y2y/2/

Comment: Hi Andreas, one question about this. Is it possible to recognize if the user enters a blank character after the comme. in this case the search would not work anymore. in other words is it possible to tell the plugin to ignore a blank at start?

Comment: @tBook I modified the code and the jsFiddle. Basically in the split() function you need to take into accounts the possible blank spaces: `val.split( /,\s*/ )` and you also need to trim the search term before comparison: `request.term = $.trim(request.term)`.

If you like the answer you can upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the best solution is to put the numbers in another field which is not autocomplete.

You can do that with the function 'onItemSelect' of this plugin https://github.com/dyve/jquery-autocomplete

Comment: Thanks for your replay, unfortunately This should work with only one field. I am a litter bit furhter, I think the characters replace could work something with     select: function (event, ui){
      value = $("#tags").val(); 
      value = value.replace(/\D/g,'');
      $("#tags").val(value);    
} but where I´m struggling is the part that a user can insert a new name after the comma means that jquery only takes the value after the comma ...

Comment: I talked to the client, I can use a second input. Thanks!